# Where does python3's requests module store the cookie

Tags: python-3.x, sql-injection

So, here is my problem, I want to test the blind SQL injection based on boolean, which is a login form, I judge the correctness by the length of the response message, but after I logged in, the cookie is saved, and I'll always be logged in, I just want to delete the cookie which is stored by python 3, can anyone give me an suggestion.

Here is my code

```
import requests
url="https://www.example.com/admin"
params={
    "login":" or ((select user()) LIKE 'a%')#",
    "passwd":"xxxxxx"
} 

html=requests.post(url,data=params)
print(len(html.text))
```